# How to use Python and R in GitLab CI?

Tags: python, r, docker, gitlab

I have a simple GitLab CI pipeline that originally only required Python (>=3.5). The code I've been working on is just to test a prototype, so after realising there are some R libraries that already implement some of the required steps, I began using `rpy2` which means that now the CI requires both Python and R.

From what I understand, GitLab CI takes the images from Docker Hub but I was unable to find an image just containing both languages (in the versions that I require). I guess my option is to use the image of an OS and run the commands to install both languages in the pipeline, but that may require a lot of space, is there a simple easy way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use echo "Hello world" to run the containers.

Comment: But what would be the base image there? Do you need to add something like `alpine`? Sorry, I haven't used Docker in a while.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to use the image `'rpy2/rpy2'` which contains R and Python 2, and run `apt install python3`. Probably not the best option, but it works.